# Writing to a file via subprocess.run() and TextIOWrapper.write() mixed up

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

While running the following code snippet

```py
import subprocess

with open('test', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foo\n')
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'bar'], stdout=f)
```

I actually expected a file `test` being created where the first line equals `foo` and the second line equals `bar`. However, it turns out the reversed order is the case, i.e., the file equals

```
bar
foo
```

I'm wonder how the correct pythonic version of the above code snippet has to look like where first `foo` is written and then `bar`. Of course, I can split the two operations into two different `with` statements like:

```py
import subprocess

with open('test', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foo\n')
with open('test', 'a') as f:
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'bar'], stdout=f)
```

Though, this is rather bad in the sense that the file must be opened/closed two times, now. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely happening due to implicit buffering on the file.

If you add an explicit `flush()` *after* writing `foo` but before launching the subprocess, it should work as expected:

```
import subprocess

with open('test', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foo\n')
    f.flush()
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'bar'], stdout=f)
```

Alternatively, you could disable buffering on the file *when you open it*. This is generally not recommended unless you know what you're doing, as many I/O patterns will degrade without buffering:

```
import subprocess

with open('test', 'w', buffering=1) as f:
    f.write('foo\n')
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'bar'], stdout=f)
```

Technically, the above is not *disabling* buffering but enabling *line-oriented* buffering. That is, the file will automatically flush whenever you write a newline (as you're doing after writing "foo"). To fully disable buffering, you need to write in binary mode:

```
import subprocess

with open('test', 'wb', buffering=0) as f:
    f.write(b'foo\n')
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'bar'], stdout=f)
```